# Redcar Install through RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am trying to install Redcar on Ubuntu using RVM. I have read countless articles about it and i still get this error message.

I followed this article in particular.
http://azazeal.xelixis.net/post/How-to-install-Redcar-editor-under-Ubuntu-1010-with-RVM.aspx

Do you guys know what I am missing here?

```
atrosity@AtroBuntu:~$ redcar
Redcar 0.11 ( x86_64-linux )
java -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/atrosity/.redcar/assets/jruby-complete-1.5.3.jar -                   Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Xmx320m -Xss1024k -Djruby.memory.max=320m -Djruby.stack.max=1024k org.jruby.Main /home/atrosity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@redcar/gems/redcar-0.11/bin/redcar --no-sub-jruby --ignore-stdin --start-time=1309244948
/home/atrosity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@redcar/gems/redcar-0.11/lib/redcar/runner.rb:44:in `exec': No such file or directory - java -Xbootclasspath/a:/home/atrosity/.redcar/assets/jruby-complete-1.5.3.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Xmx320m -Xss1024k -Djruby.memory.max=320m -Djruby.stack.max=1024k org.jruby.Main /home/atrosity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@redcar/gems/redcar-0.11/bin/redcar --no-sub-jruby --ignore-stdin --start-time=1309244948 (Errno::ENOENT)
from /home/atrosity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@redcar/gems/redcar-0.11/lib/redcar/runner.rb:44:in `run'
from /home/atrosity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@redcar/gems/redcar-0.11/lib/redcar/runner.rb:80:in `construct_command'
from /home/atrosity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@redcar/gems/redcar-0.11/lib/redcar/runner.rb:43:in `run'
from /home/atrosity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@redcar/gems/redcar-0.11/lib/redcar.rb:81:in `spin_up'
from /home/atrosity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@redcar/gems/redcar-0.11/bin/redcar:32
from /home/atrosity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@redcar/bin/redcar:19:in `load'
from /home/atrosity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@redcar/bin/redcar:19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key statement here is ``exec': No such file or directory - java`

Check out [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redcar-editor/MgN-YCRzwjw) on the RedCar mailing list. It looks like you probably don't have java installed. RedCar is a JRuby application so you need Java for it to function

The [Java Ubuntu installation documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) should help you to install Java. Once that's done, it should just work